# URL in Todonotes do not work if # is included

Tags: hyperref, urls, todonotes

I'm searching for a way to have a URL with a `#` in a todonote.

I tried to add `caption{}` to the `todonote`, ànd that works for basic URLs (just as these urls work without the `caption{}`). It does not work for URLs with a `#`:

See my MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\todo[inline, caption={}]{see this example url that works
 \url{http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Francis_Crick}. 
 And this one that does not 
 \url{http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Francis_Crick#Quote_mine}. 
}
\end{document}
```

first link: http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Francis_Crick

second link: http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Francis_Crick#Quote_mine

I'm glad for any advice whether this is at all possible, e.g. whether this works with some other packages!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use escape character for the hash: `\#`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\todo[inline, caption={}]{see this example url that works \url{http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Francis_Crick}. And this one that does not \url{http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Francis_Crick\#Quote_mine}. }
\end{document}
```

Also note: your original MWE doesn't compile (it doesn't have a documentclass) and your first url doesn't have the backslash in front (`url` instead of `\url`). Please make sure to be precise and correct in an MWE to facilitate the answering process.

Comment: ai, thanks for the hints, I will edit the post right away. And of course also thanks for the solution to the problem :-)